# concatenate uploaded image file names

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

im using the below code to upload multiple images, take the image file name, concatenate with “,” and return the value so it can be used to insert into the database using CodeIgniter.

The problem that im having is im unable to concatenate the file names using implode().

Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

```
function upload(){
      $config['upload_path'] = './uploadsim/'; 
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg';
      $config['max_size']  = '0';
      $config['max_width']  = '0';
      $config['max_height']  = '0';
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {

        $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'.$i);

        if($upload === FALSE) continue;

        $images = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
        $imagename= $images['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $impl=  implode(",", $imagename);


  }
     return $impl;

}
```

Comment: what is the output of `print_r` or `var_dump` of `$images`?

Comment: @imm  http://pastie.org/2730453 for the var_dump of $images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the notation on image name to build up an array

```
$imagename[] = $images['upload_data']['file_name'];
```

then move your implode to outside of the loop

```
return implode(",", $imagename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will only get the filename of the last file the way the code is showing (if works at all). To samve the image name concated with a , you can do a couple of things.

```
$imagename = ""; #before the for loop
$imagename .= ',' . $images['upload_data']['file_name']; #in the for loop
```

or

```
$imagename[($i-1)] = $images['upload_data']['file_name']; # in the for loop
$impl = imploade(",",$imagename; # outside the for loop
```

Comment: @Chandresh - The only items outside the for loop is the declaration of the $imagename and the implode lines. other wise the implode will be happening for every iteration of the for loop. Look at the comments at the end of the code lines. It states where that line would end up.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do some change in this code..

```
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {

        $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'.$i);

        if($upload === FALSE) continue;

        $images = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
        $imagename[] = $images['upload_data']['file_name'];


  }
$impl =  implode(",", $imagename);

return $impl;
```